# ASP.Net WebAPI Swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

How do I specify whether a property on a model is optional/required in order for that to carry through to the generated swagger documentation?

e.g. (simple example)

```
/api/Authenticate

Authenticate(AuthRequest request)
{ }

AuthRequest()
{
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try using the `[Required]` attribute on the properties you want as mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Nkosi: try using the [Required] attribute on the properties you want as mandatory